# Unable to join tables with different number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Lets say we have 2 tables :

Table X :

```
A | B | C | D |
---------------
1  2    abc somedate
2  4    xyz somedate
3  5    abc somedate
4  7    xyz somedate
```

Table Y :

```
A | E | C | Z |
---------------
1  2    abc somedate
2  4    xyz somedate
3  5    abc somedate
4  7    xyz somedate
```

Lets say A and C are primary and foreign keys for both tables.

now i want to sum the values of B in table X by checking if a D date falls between a given start and end date and join this result with table Y which should return count(E) by checking if Z falls between a given start and end date.

How can I achieve this in a single query?

I tried separate queries on both tables and they both would return a different set of rows. So im not sure how can i combine both and return the result in 1 query.

Comment: You should really show the results you want.  A Fiddle of some sort would be helpful too.

Comment: "Join table X to table Y" is not a meaningful operation. You must state explicitly on what condition(s) you are joining; otherwise the default is a Cartesian join, which is perfectly valid but also exceptionally rarely the correct kind of join for a specific business problem you are trying to solve. Any attempt at answering your question without getting this clarification from you will be very unlikely to be helpful in any way.

Answer (score 0):

not sure to have the well understanding.

But as I understand you want to have a SQL query with the result of two differents.
It not seems to be a JOIN but a UNION.

Let me propose the following:

```
(SELECT SUM(B) AS sumofb FROM X WHERE D BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate)
UNION
(SELECT COUNT(E) AS countofe FROM Y WHERE Z BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate);
```